# Change specific values of dataframe columns, what is the most efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I need to change the values of specific items in the dataframe column, I used a for loop to do it manually, is there a way using idioms or .where, that is more efficient? I believe the code below is not the best way to do it...

```
# change the names of the countries as requested
for index, row in energy.iterrows(): #change the name of specific 
countries
if energy.loc[index, ['Country']].str.contains('United States of 
America').bool():
    energy.loc[index, ['Country']] = 'United States'
    print(energy.loc[index, ['Country']])

if energy.loc[index, ['Country']].str.contains('Republic of 
Korea').bool():
    energy.loc[index, ['Country']] = 'South Korea'
    print(energy.loc[index, ['Country']])

if energy.loc[index, ['Country']].str.contains('United Kingdom of Great 
Britain and Northern Ireland').bool():
    energy.loc[index, ['Country']] = 'United Kingdom'
    print(energy.loc[index, ['Country']])

if energy.loc[index, ['Country']].str.contains('China, Hong Kong 
Special Administrative Region').bool():
    energy.loc[index, ['Country']] = 'Hong Kong'
    print(energy.loc[index, ['Country']])
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and also format your code correctly.  Both will make it easier for others to (a) help you and (b) learn from your question!

Comment: Do you need to use `str.contains` (i.e. partial matching) or is exact matching sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.where`

```
energy['Country'] = np.where(energy['Country'] == 'United States of America', 'United States', energy['Country'] )
energy['Country'] = np.where(energy['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea', 'Korea', energy['Country'])
```

Or:

```
energy['Country'][energy['Country'] == 'United States of America'] = 'United States'
energy['Country'][energy['Country'] == 'Republic of Korea'] = 'Korea'
```

df:

```
                    Country
0  United States of America
1                     Spain
2         Republic of Korea
3                    France
```

Output:

```
         Country
0  United States
1          Spain
2          Korea
3         France
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dictionary with the mapping and then use `map`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

mapVal = {'United States of America': 'United States', 'Republic of Korea': 'South Korea', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom', 'China': 'Hong Kong', 'Hong Kong Special Administrative Region': 'Hong Kong'}    #Sample Mapping

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United States of America', 'Republic of Korea', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', 'China', 'Hong Kong Special Administrative Region']})
df["newVal"] = df["Country"].map(mapVal)          #df["Country"] = df["Country"].map(mapVal)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             Country          newVal
0                           United States of America   United States
1                                  Republic of Korea     South Korea
2  United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern I...  United Kingdom
3                                              China       Hong Kong
4            Hong Kong Special Administrative Region       Hong Kong
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method:

```
energy
                                             Country
0                           United States of America
1                                  Republic of Korea
2  United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern I...
3     China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region

energy.replace(rep_map)
          Country
0   United States
1     South Korea
2  United Kingdom
3       Hong Kong
```

Note that `replace()` will replace all instances of these strings across a data frame.

Data:

```
countries = ["United States of America", 
             "Republic of Korea", 
             "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", 
             "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region"]
replacements = ["United States", "South Korea", "United Kingdom", "Hong Kong"]
rep_map = {k:v for k, v in zip(countries, replacements)}
energy = pd.DataFrame({"Country": countries})
```